# Installing TP-LINK TL-WN722N without internet

Tags: wireless

I'd like to install the wireless receiver TP LINK TL-WN722N on my desktop computer (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) without using internet connection, how do I do that?

I'm currently using a BOLT's mobile wifi to connect to the internet with my laptop. I've been trying to find ways to connect it with no success.

Could you please help me with clear detail steps? If there's any file that I need to download from websites, I can do that through my laptop and transfer it to the desktop comp with my USB.

*desperately needed help >,<

Thank you. :)

Comment: You need an internet connection in any case so that you can get the driver. Use a wired connection if need be. Or copy over the files from a machine with an internet connection.

Comment: yup, that's what i meant. I've internet connection for the laptop but not the desktop. So if i've to download things i can do that on my laptop and then copy them over to the desktop.

Comment: what i wanna do is to set the TP LINK TL WN722N on my desktop so that it can access the internet through it with the mobile wifi.

Comment: i've followed the link, but when i put the 'sudo apt-get update' command, it asked for a password and when i tried to put in the password the keyboard didn't work. No matter how many times I tried, it always ends up that way. Could you tell me why? What should I do now?